# How to make this flutter screen responsive according to different screen sizes?

Tags: flutter, web, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I tried some plugins also for responsive this app screen.But it doesn't worked.How to create this responsive with mediaquery ? Does mediaquery is enough for this ?

Answer (score 1):

To make a Flutter app responsive using MediaQuery class,
you can modify the build function like:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        body: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600
            ? _landscapeforWeb()
            : _portraitLayout());
  }
```

If the width is **greater than 600**, it'd return a larger view accordingly.
MediaQuery does work for me and is enough for responsive design in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LayoutBuilder` to return widget based on screen size like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
//here I just use small and large screens .
  final Widget largeScreen;

  // final Widget mediumScreen;
  final Widget smallScreen;

  const ResponsiveWidget({Key key, @required this.largeScreen, this.smallScreen}) : super(key: key);

  static bool isSmallScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <800;
  }
  static bool isMediumScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 700 && MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1000;
  }
  static bool isLargeScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >=800;
  }
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > 800) {
          return largeScreen;
        } else
          return smallScreen;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then call this `ReposnsiveWidget` and pass small and large screen widgets:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ResponsiveWidget(
                largeScreen: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: blogList(),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                smallScreen: blogList(),
              )
    );
  }
```

Comment: @Nadun Did this help you? please accept the answer if helped.